# Wordpress get a custom meta information

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```
 <?php 
$is_wrappable = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_is_gift_wrappable', true );

if($is_wrappable == 'true'){
echo "Want this gift wrapped?  <a href='".get_permalink($product_id)."'>Click here.</a>";
}


?>
```

I am trying to get a post meta information added by a plugin. But it is not working.

Actually, is the product id and the post id the same?

Sorry I thing I get it:

```
<?php 
global $post;
global $product;

$is_wrappable = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_is_gift_wrappable', true );

if ( $is_wrappable == '' && $this->gift_wrap_enabled ) {
$is_wrappable = 'yes';
}

if ( $is_wrappable == 'yes' ) 
echo "Want this gift wrapped?  <a href='".get_permalink($product_id)."'>Click here.</a>";

?>
```

Comment: Can you give us more details about your main query? 
From where do you get the `$product->id` ?

Comment: `$post` and `$product` are *not* the same, though `$post->ID` will equal `$product->id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($is_wrappable){
    echo "Want this gift wrapped?  <a href='".get_permalink($product_id)."'>Click here.</a>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but I think the problem is, I am not getting the information in $is_wrappable.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing this other plugin or you showing us how the post meta `_is_gift_wrappable` is being *saved* it is hard/impossible for us to write precise conditionals. However, if we assume that it is a checkbox WooCommerce usually saves checkbox meta as "yes" or "no" since true booleans (aka true and false) are kind of funky in meta.

```
global $product;

$is_wrappable = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_is_gift_wrappable', true );

// dump the value for debug purposes. delete when finished. 
var_dump($is_wrappable);

if($is_wrappable == 'yes'){
echo "Want this gift wrapped?  <a href='".get_permalink($product->id)."'>Click here.</a>";
}
```

Alternatively the meta key could *exist* if true and not exist if not wrappable, in which case `if($is_wrappable)` would be sufficient for conditional logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply try to use `$post->id` instead of `$product->id`. By setting `global $post,$product;` you'd be able to retrieve custom fields from anywhere.

```
<?php
 global $post, $product;

 $is_wrappable = get_post_meta( $post->id, '_is_gift_wrappable', true );

 if($is_wrappable == '') {
  echo "Want this gift wrapped? <a href='".get_permalink($product_id)."'>Click here.</a>";
 }

?>
```

Be sure you're setting the right prefix "_is_gift_wrappable" for the field you're trying to retrieve data from.